# Add 0 at the begin of file in order to have group of 5 bit

Tags: bash, math, sh

I have a file with some 01, for example

```
11011000101000111010001100101010010100010110010101110111011101011011111111100100010011001111100011011111100010001100010111011111011010111000101000000110010010
```

My goal is to have group of 5 char with bash script.
In this case I have 158 characters and I don't get group of 5 char.

```
11011
00010
10001
11010
00110
01010
10010
10001
01100
10101
11011
10111
01011
01111
11111
00100
01001
10011
11100
01101
11111
00010
00110
00101
11011
11101
10101
11000
10100
00001
10010
010
```

I need to add two zero (in this scenario) in order to have group of 5 characters (or bits).

Comment: And you want to add them at the beginning?

Comment: You will need a loop that will add zeroes until the file length modulo 5 is zero.

Comment: What do you want your result to look like?

Comment: yes at the beginning

Comment: I think the best would be to modify the original script instead. But you did not provide it...

Answer (score 1):

With bash, you could do:

```
zeros=00000
printf "${zeros:0:$(( 5 - ${#input} % 5 ))}%s" "$input"
```

(where input is your input string).

Comment: `zeros=00000
printf "${zeros:0:$(( 5 - ${cat test.txt} % 5 ))}%s" "test.txt" `

I tried with cat But I get  bad substitution

Comment: You want `$(cat test.txt)`

Comment: (round parens, not braces)

Comment: Note that, as written, this will prepend 5 `0`s when the string is already well-balanced.

Comment: I need to understand How many 0 Ineed to add, it's my problem

Comment: Or, rather, you want `input=$(cat test.txt)`.  You cant compute the length of the output of `cat` using `${#..` notation

Comment: the number of zeros you need to prepend is ( 5 - n%5 )%5, where n is the length of the string

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk and `FPAT`:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FPAT="[01]{5}"
    OFS="\n"
}
{
    $0=sprintf("%0" 5-length%5 "d%s",0,$0)
    $1=$1
}
1' file
```

Output:

```
00110
11000
...
01100
10010
```